# What is a good tool for this job involving the prime spiral?

Tags: prime-numbers, math-software

I'm interested in studying the prime spiral interactively.

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11056/ulam-spiral-is-there-an-unusual-amount-of-clumping-in-prime-rich-quadratic-po) talks about some interesting patterns in the spiral involving quadratic equations. The idea I had was, write a program that outputs all values of a polynomial for a certain domain, output values to a list, and check for elements in common with another list, based on another polynomial of that same form. I'd want to make some plots.

What's a good way to play around this using an interpreter? I've never used Octave. Is that the kind of thing it's good for? Or Sage?

Comment: Octave's a bit more suitable for computations involving inexact arithmetic. For number-theoretic investigations, you'd want a system that can do exact integer/rational arithmetic, like Maple or *Mathematica*. Sage can do exact arithmetic, I'm told, but I've no experience with it.

Comment: @ixtmixilix for this kind of tests I use Python: it is possible to do all the things you initially want, here you can review some examples of plots: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1412264/what-methods-are-known-to-visualize-patterns-in-the-set-of-real-roots-of-quadrat